# Current Month in Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, formula

I am trying to determine if a project is due within 1 month (30 days) to return a value of "True" or "False". This is the formula that I tried but gave an error:

if([Project ETC].[Date]<TODAY+30,"False","True"))

And tried this as well,

if([Project ETC].[Date]<DATEADD([Project ETC],1,MONTH,"False","True"))

Comment: `'Project ETC'[Date]<(TODAY()+30)`

Comment: Has this been solved already by the suggestion of Ron? If not, please include the error...